# mongo geospatial query with additional location parameters

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Given the following documents:

```
{
  _id: 'foo'
  locations: [
    {
      lat: 1,
      lon: 2,
      type: 'home'
    },
    {
      lat: 10,
      lon: 20,
      type: 'office'
    }
  ]
}

{
  _id: 'bar'
  locations: [
    {
      lat: 10,
      lon: 20,
      type: 'home'
    },
    {
      lat: 1,
      lon: 2,
      type: 'office'
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to find all documents near a location with a specific type?

For example, the query:
`db.objects.find({locations: {$near: {lat: 1, lon: 2}, $maxDistance: 1}, 'locations.type': 'home'})`

returns both foo and bar because both have a location with type 'home' and a location near [1,2]

What I want the query to do is find just foo since it's home location is near [1,2]

Comment: are you open to changing your schema?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider changing your schema.  Instead of a single document with an array of locations, consider multiple documents each representing a single location with a designation of the type.

The type of query you need to execute here requires $elemMatch to guarantee meeting both of your conditions *on the same array element* - for this we use elemMatch.   Unfortunately it does not work for geoSpatial query - at least there is no way to construct it currently.  There is an outstanding [Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3325) to make it work.